# Express static files URL changes based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I have  create-react-app thats using react-router-dom.  I'm also using express server-side-rendering for SEO.  Below is my simple express config.  When I got to the '/' route or any of the first-level routes ("/contact", "/blog", etc), it works as intended.  The static files come in as:

"http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.ec91a01d.css".

But when I navigate to any multi-level routes ("/blog/blog-post-1"), it adds the first route to the static files URl ex:

http://localhost:8080/blog/static/js/main.d9a1d852.js

What am I doing wrong?  Also, the folder structure is that of a regular Create-react-app.  Im serving my index.html from the build folder and my styles/js from build/static.

```
Project
----build
----public
...etc
```

And my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ssr = require('./ssr.mjs');

const app = express();

const crawler = async (req, res) => {
  const isBot = req.get('User-Agent').indexOf('Googlebot') > -1 || 
  req.get('User-Agent').indexOf('googlebot') > -1;
  if (isBot) {
    const { html } = await ssr(`http://www.example.com${req.path}`);
    return res.status(200).send(html);
  }
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'));
};
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.get('/', crawler);

app.get('/process', crawler);
app.get('/work', crawler);
app.get('/contact', crawler);
app.get('/blog', crawler);
app.get('/blog/create-post', crawler);
app.get('/blog/:id', crawler);
app.get('/services', crawler);
app.get('/services/:id', crawler);
app.get('/payments', crawler);



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server started. Press Ctrl+C to quit'));
```

Comment: When my index.html is built, the `href` of the css and the `src` of the js start with `/static/...`, meaning the current browser location is irrelevant. I'm not sure you're doing something wrong necessarily, it's possible that server-side rendering and react-router simply won't work together. Plus, [Google is rendering React apps anyway](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/seo-vs-react-is-it-neccessary-to-render-react-pages-in-the-backend-74ce5015c0c9) when crawling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be fetching your ressources with relative paths in your `index.html`, e.g.

```
<script src="./static/js/main.d9a1d852.js"></script>
```

What you want are absolute paths:

```
<script src="/static/js/main.d9a1d852.js"></script>
```

Notice the missing `.` at the beginning of the path.

Comment: to add to this: If your src looks like this `static/js/blah/blah/blah.js`, then that is also a relative path. The `/` at the beginning is what makes it an absolute path.